# How to use autofiltering option of datagrid columns after binding it to a datasource at runtime, in windows form , C#

Tags: c#, datagrid

I need to use the autofiltering option of datagrid column so that users are able to filter out the data, like the option in excel. I have seen the example in Microsoft official site, and I know how that works. But the thing is, I am binding the datasource at runtime, instead of creating a datasource at design view , and editing the columns manually.

And after binding it at runtime, I am trying to add the autofiltering option. But it is not working. The following code is adding extra columns since new columns are created eve after data is bound. I don't want that. I want to change the property of the bound column to be able to support autofiltering.

```
    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
    //dtenv is a datatable
    bs.DataSource = dtenv;
    datagridview1.DataSource = bs;

    foreach(DataColumn col in dtenv.Columns)
    {
      if(col.ColumnName.ToString()=="Deploy")
        {
           DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn txt = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
           txt.HeaderText = "Deploy";
           txt.Name = "Deploy";
           datagridview1.Columns.Add(txt);
         }
     else
       {
            DataGridViewAutofilterTextBoxColumn txt = new DataGridViewAutofilterTextBoxColumn();
            txt.HeaderText = col.ColumnName.ToString();
            txt.Name = col.ColumnName.ToString();
            datagridview1.Columns.Add(txt);

    }
```

Now, I know the above code is incorrect, as it is adding more columns after the data is bound, but the previous code didn't have any binding source and each column was added every loop and then a separate loop was there to add individual rows. Now if I don't use the binding source, the headercolumns show the filtering buttons, but those buttons don't work.

Please let me know how to fix this. I want to avoid creating a datasource at design view as it is not feasible for our project.

Comment: Hi, Please help me out with this. It is very urgent, and i have to implement it today itself

Comment: Hi,I am able to do it successfully, but the datagrid eventhandlers Cellclick event and rowpostpaintevent are interferring with this autofiltering feature.